# Checking database files for physical fragmentation

Tags: sql-server, fragmentation, san

I searched the Internet and did not find clear explanation for when I should try defragmenting physical database files for a DB residing on a SAN. I understand that there are tools and procedures inside some SANs that deal with that, but also there are SANs which lack those features.

My question has 3 parts:

- How to check for physical fragmentation of database files?
- Is it necessary to do this if the files reside on a SAN?
- Is it necessary to create bigger physical database files to avoid fragmentation?

We use a rented virtual server. The database is growing and we have some strange problems. I want to be sure that defragmentation is not an issue. Also I am just generally curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

- You can check for the physical fragmentation of the disk by going to the drive, right clicking on it and selecting tools, then defragment.  Or close to that, depending on which version of the OS you are using your specific steps may be different.  But you will only be able to see the fragmentation on a volume level, not specific files.
- For the most part, no, you don't need to worry about physical fragmentation of your files if you are using a SAN (unless the SAN is dedicated to this one purpose).  Due to how most SANs are used, your IO is going to be random; which is fine since you should have LOTS of spindles to spread the load out.
- Larger physical database files would prevent fragmentation, but again, you shouldn't worry about that if you are on a SAN.  The more important thing to make sure of is that when the file grows, it grows at a set size (rather than percentage) and that size is sufficient to handle a good amount of growth.  You would want to grow the file to what you estimate the required size will be in X days and THEN defragment the volume.

This [link - Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-san-best-practices/) goes into more detail and should include some more information you can use to either prove or disprove that the SAN is the reason for your bottleneck.